# How can I optimize a MySQL server for queries without joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

- All tables in the database have one timestamp column [`float`]
  followed by an arbitrary amount of parameter columns [`integer`]
  (usually less than 5, but more than 1), and one value column
  [`float`].
- All queries are without any joins, and they are based on giving the database a set of parameters, and receiving the timestamp and value columns back.
- The amount of rows are counted in low 10s of millions.
- Small number of users, less than 10.
- More reads than writes, but both can be simultaneous.
- Should meet ACID properties.

Back in the day all MySQL was chosen, but this is a moot point. SQLite is quick and effortless on a computer local basis, but in this example it needs to be a proper server/client database. Up until this point no optimization has taken place, except for indexing.

EDIT:

I didn't mention it properly, but the traffic is not an issue. That is, it's not really an optimization for meeting certain volume criteria, it's an optimization on pure speed.

Comment: What's your question? The title is "Can I optimize a MySQL server for queries without joins?" and you stated that "All queries are without any joins" ... So ... kind of confused here.

Comment: I'm not interested in optimizing the queries. I'm interested in optimizing the database itself. That is, storage engine, buffer sizes, etc. I just thought I'd specify the nature of the queries to make it easier to understand how the database is used.

Comment: What is the volume (transactions per second) for read and write?

Comment: Generally the transactions per second is low, let's say 1 read per second and 1 write per minute or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use InnoDB for ACID support.
- Memory, memory, memory.  The single best MySQL tuning optimization you can do for reads is to increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  But of course not so high that it grows larger than your physical RAM because that can cause mysqld to go into swap.
- Structure your table's primary key along the column you most frequently search against.  That is, take advantage of InnoDB's clustered index on the primary key.

Comment: Will a composite (multi column) primary key when using InnoDB affect performance?

Comment: Make sure the leftmost columns in the composite primary key are the columns that you query against.